# SQL creating an event in an after insert trigger

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

For my database, I have to archive a video at a certain unix timestamp which is stored in the database. So, I thought it would be easy enough to create a trigger which runs after insert into the table, and then create an event to schedule the archiving of the video. I wrote the following SQL statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `ArchiveVido_onInsert` AFTER INSERT ON `tableName`FOR EACH ROW
    CREATE EVENT archiveVideo
      ON SCHEDULE AT inserted.Time_to_Archive
      DO
        UPDATE MediaPage SET is_archived = 1;
```

But I get the following error:

```
#1576 Recursion of EVENT DDL statements is forbidden when body is present
```

How can I do what I'm attempting? Or am I just missing something? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to replace `UPDATE MediaPage SET is_archived = 1;` with more or less `SET [NEW.|OLD.]is_archived = 1`

Comment: Either way, it's not letting me create the trigger

Comment: it should `OLD` and `NEW ` are valid trigger keywords see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) for examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run [statements that cause an implicit commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html) inside a trigger. That includes any DDL statement that defines or modifies a database object (CREATE EVENT counts).

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html says:

> The trigger cannot use statements that explicitly or implicitly begin or end a transaction...

Instead, you should defining a general EVENT that runs periodically and updates any videos that need to be archived.

```
CREATE EVENT archiveVideo
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
  DO 
    UPDATE MediaPage SET is_archived = 1 
    WHERE is_archived = 0 AND Time_to_Archive < NOW()
    LIMIT 1000;
```

Make sure there's an index on `(is_archived, Time_to_Archive)` so the WHERE clause is optimized to match the rows to update.

I added `LIMIT 1000` so it wouldn't try to update too many rows in a single transaction. If there are more than 1000 videos to archive at a given time, they'll have to wait 1 more minute for the event to run again.

Comment: This is a great idea. Thank you so much!